# Format whole row of table using overbraces and underbraces

Tags: tables

I want to use exact same format in latex, please provide me code for this.

I can only make a simple row but not able to put overbraces and underbraces.

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \begin{document}
     \begin{tabular}{ |c|c| } 
     \hline
     Physical page \# & pageoffset(12 bits) \\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
 \end{document}
```

I already spend hour searching about this but result was not obtained.
can u plz show me ?

Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as \documentclass{}...\begin{document} etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a minimal working example (MWE) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: Sir i apologize for that, I am completely new to latex and all of sudden i had to do this to represent my document.
I searched a lot and tried by my own but failed to setup this kind of alignment.

Comment: I would look for questions about tables and underbrace and overbrace.

Comment: Sir if possible please give me some skeleton, I am sure this wont be more than 2 minute task for u, but for me, I already spent hours in that :(

Comment: Alternatively you do it in another software like PowerPoint or Excel and include it as an picture in your Latex document.

Comment: I already did that, this image is that one only :)
But unfortunately required task is to make in latex only :(

Comment: Strange task :). I am on my phone only. I cannot help you tonight. I still think that you should provide a basic code skeleton so that others are more motivated to help.

Comment: I did it. But that's pretty naive for experts :(
No one can get help from that. But as u suggested, i made it.
Thanks sir :)

Comment: On the contrary, it helps a little if only because we now don't have to type out the text in your picture. Now if you add the `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} \end{document}` \t least, we can copy and paste the code from your question straight into a document and we don't have to build it ourselves. Now this may not seem a big deal, but in all cases every little helps. In many cases, tough, it turns out someone's using some package or has some special requirement, which means answers can require to be rewritten.

Comment: So it's always good to supply a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `\psbrace` from `pstricks-add`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pstricks-add, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
  \psset{braceWidth=0.8pt, braceWidthInner=3pt, braceWidthOuter=3pt, nodesep=8pt, linejoin=1}
  \sffamily\everypsbox{\scriptsize}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
  physical addr. \begin{tabular}{ |c|c| }
  \hline
  Physical page \# \pnode[0pt, 2.6ex]{N1}\pnode[0pt, -1.25ex]{C1}\hspace*{2em}& \pnode[0pt, -1.25ex]{C2}pageoffs\pnode[2pt, 2.6ex]{N2}e\pnode[-2pt, 2.6ex]{N3}t(12 bits) \pnode[2pt, 2.6ex]{N4}\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \psbrace[rot=-90, nodesepA=-2.6em, nodesepB=-0.4ex](N2)(N1){\bfseries 9 bits set index}%
  \psbrace[rot=-90, nodesepA=-2.4em, nodesepB=-0.4ex](N4)(N3){5 bits line off}
  \psbrace[rot=90, nodesepA=-1.9em, nodesepB=1.7ex](C1)(C2){\bfseries\textcolor{LimeGreen}{color index} (2 bits -> 4 colors)} %
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1), but OP wait on math solution :(.

Comment: @Zarko: ??? I don't understand what is meant by a ‘maths solution’, despite I read the comments on this thread.

Comment: OP in the last comment to my solution say: *I am waiting if someone provides me maths expression  ...*  (which he/she will able further edit in equation editor). Since you also provide solution with drawing (with `pstrick`), which (I estimated) confirm that the drawings is more reasonable solution then compose table and use some math stuff. Or I misunderstand him/her?

Comment: No sir, U are correct, I want a math expression that can work on equation editors like latex.codecogs.com

Answer (score 0):

I will rather draw image as bother with table:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm,
               12pt
               ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy,%had to be after lib. decorations.pathreplacing
                fit,
                positioning
                }

\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[
 node distance = 0mm,
   start chain = going right,
every node/.style = {align=center},
    box/.style = {minimum width=#1, minimum height=9mm,
                  inner xsep=0pt, outer sep=0mm,
                  font=\large\sffamily, on chain},
BC/.style args = {#1/#2}{% Brace Calligraphic
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
        pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
        post=moveto, post length=1pt,
        raise=#1,
              #2},% for mirroring of brace
        very thick,
        pen colour=red
        },
                        ]
\node (n1) [on chain]       {physical addr.};
\node (n2) [box=12em,draw]  {Physical page \#};
\node (n3) [box= 6em]       {\quad pageoffset};
\node (n4) [box= 4em]       {(bits)};
\node[draw, inner sep=0mm, fit=(n3) (n4)] {};
%
\draw[BC=1mm/ ]    
    ([xshift=-3em] n3.north west) 
        to node[above=3mm] {9 bits\\ set index} (n3.north east);
\draw[BC=1mm/ ]
    (n4.north west) 
        to node[above=3mm] {5 bits\\ line off.} (n4.north east);
\draw[BC=1mm/mirror]
    ([xshift=-3em] n3.south west) 
        to node[below=2mm] {\textcolor{teal}{color index}\\ (2 bits $\to$ 4 colors)} 
    (n3.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.
How can i make it work for http://latex.codecogs.com/ ?

Comment: my solution is image and can not be edited as math expression. for including into your real document you need to import code in your editor.

Comment: cant it possible without image ?

Comment: maybe, but is suggest to draw a picture, not coding table or math expression. If you like to have such solution, than you need to wait on someone else solution :(

Comment: ohk :)
I am waiting if someone provides me maths expression.
Anyways, thanks a ton sir for ur kind efforts :)